# How to switch bootstrap tabs in Geb functional test in grails?

Tags: grails, functional-testing, spock, geb

Ні! That's my first question here.

I'm using grails 3.1.7 and inbuilt Spock with Geb.

I'm trying to switch between two bootstrap tabs inside the same page to avoid ElementNotVisibleException.

Here is some code (with several lines omitted):

Markup:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="${registerActive ? '' : 'active'}"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#login">...</a></li>
    <li class="${registerActive ? 'active' : ''}"><a id="registerTab" data-toggle="tab" href="#register">...</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="login" class="tab-pane fade ${registerActive ? '' : 'in active'}">
        <g:form ...>
            <div>
                <g:field type="email" name="username" />
            </div>
            ...
        </g:form>
    </div>

    <div id="register" class="tab-pane fade ${registerActive ? 'in active' : ''}">
        <g:form ...>
            <div>
                <g:field type="email" name="email"/>
            </div>
            ...
        </g:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Test:

```
void "register"() {
    when:"user logged in"
    register 'testUser@gmail.com', 'passW0rd!' ...

    then: ...
}

    private register(String email, String password ...) {
    go "/"
    $('#registerTab').click()
    $('input[name=email]').value(email)
    $('input[name=password]').value(password)
    ...
    $('input[name=register]').click()
}
```

Attempt to access "email" field causes ElementNotVisibleException.

I also tried adding and removing **active** class using jquery property.

But with no result, the form still remains invisible for Geb.

What am I doing wrong? Could one please suggest the proper way to switch between two tabs inside the distinct page?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Added several pieces of code trying to omit the not necessary ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is way in the past, but in case anyone else needs a solution, here is one. I created a javascript function like:

```
function changeTabs(tabNumber) {
    $('a[href$="container' + tabNumber + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

Then, in my Geb test, I changed the tab with the following line:

```
js.changeTabs('3')
```

This works with the ChromeDriver which is what we are using.

Comment: Actually, I wrapped it in a grails "if" statement. It doesn't get generated, unless it is a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hitting this problem because it takes a while for the tab to be visible.

As described here - http://www.gebish.org/async

> Asynchronicity
>
> Modern web pages are full of asynchronous operations like AJAX
>   requests and animations. Geb provides built in support for this fact
>   of life.
>
> Any content lookup, or operation can be wrapped in a waitFor clause.

In your case, it should be something like:

```
go "/"
$('#registerTab').click()
waitFor {
    $('input[name=email]').value(email)
}
```

Comment: Definitely not. Sleeps or waitFor doesn't help, the element still remains invisible.

It seems the tab doesn't switch because of the JavaScript is disabled. But when I enable it I have problems with statements like _go "/"_. 

The only solution that worked for me was explicit addition of class **active** to the div with the needed form. But it's ugly.

Probably I'll divide login and register forms into different pages with different URLs.

Comment: It seems that the problem is related to issues with javascript support by HtmlUnit driver.